# hebrew fonts have squares around them..how does one fix this?

Tags: fonts

After a recent updates hebrew fonts have started to appear with squares around them

[image: example:]

Anyone know how to fix this? i tried changing to various fonts with no sucsess

this is my current font setup:

```
    ; fonts in linux
(if (string= system-name "zlap")
;(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Inconsolata-16"))
;(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Source Code Pro-18"))
;(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Pragmata Pro-19"))
;(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Fantasque Sans Mono 14"))
;(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "monaco 19"))
;(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Office Code Pro-18"))
;(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Hack 19"))
;(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . " mononoki 19"))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "fira mono 17"))
)

;; fontso in Win
;(if (system-type-is-win)
;(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Consolas-14"))
;)
(if (string= system-name "zbeast")
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "fira mono 23"))
```

)

Comment: Does this affect every buffer with Hebrew letters?

Comment: thx for the response. this seems to happen in several buffers (org,elfeed,etc ) but i think its mainly in headers (org headers etc). the inline text seems to be presented ok

Comment: Curious... I've tried Org-mode headers with Yiddish and the letters look normal - no squares whatsoever. My setting for `default-frame-alist` is `STANDARD`. Do you use the default version of Org-mode or the one from MELPA?